# Even though device is cpu, a gpu error occurs

Tags: cuda, tensorflow

I am trying to run a net (convolution, highway, fc, rnn) which is too big for the GPU. Thus I am defining the device, globally, as "cpu". Still when executing the script, after building the model, when initializing the variables, the script throws a gpu error.

```
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.device("cpu:0"):
      model = CNN_FC_LANGUAGE(sess, checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.checkpoint_dir,
                                      char_embed_dim=FLAGS.char_embed_dim,
                                      summaries_dir=FLAGS.summaries_dir,
                                      feature_maps=eval(FLAGS.feature_maps),
                                      kernels=eval(FLAGS.kernels),
                                      batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
                                      dropout_prob=FLAGS.dropout_prob,
                                      forward_only=FLAGS.forward_only,
                                      seq_length=FLAGS.seq_length,
                                      prediction_starts=FLAGS.prediction_starts,
                                      prediction_length=FLAGS.prediction_length,
                                      use_char=FLAGS.use_char,
                                      highway_layers=FLAGS.highway_layers,
                                      rnn_size=FLAGS.rnn_size,
                                      rnn_layer_depth=FLAGS.rnn_layer_depth,
                                      use_batch_norm=FLAGS.use_batch_norm,
                                      run_name=run_name,
                                      data_dir=FLAGS.data_dir)

      model.run(FLAGS.epoch, FLAGS.learning_rate, FLAGS.learning_rate_decay, FLAGS.net2net)
```

In all the used scripts a search for "gpu" does give 0 results.
Also, when creating the model I print all the tensor names. The device is also printed. When searching for "gpu" here, also I get 0 results.

Still, when the script runs it throws a CUDA-error. But why would it allocate any memory on the GPU if device is explicitely set to CPU?

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1034] failed to alloc 2147483648 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 2147483648
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1034] failed to alloc 1932735232 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 1932735232
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1034] failed to alloc 1739461632 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 1739461632
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1034] failed to alloc 1565515520 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 1565515520
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1034] failed to alloc 1408964096 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 1408964096
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1034] failed to alloc 4294967296 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 4294967296
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1034] failed to alloc 4294967296 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 4294967296
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1034] failed to alloc 4294967296 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 4294967296
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1034] failed to alloc 4294967296 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 4294967296
Killed
```

Any ideas? Thx

Edit: Also when building the graph tensorflow echos:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.468
pciBusID 0000:04:00.0
Total memory: 3.94GiB
Free memory: 3.64GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0)
```

But why? I told it to only use the cpu, right?

Comment: Have you tried running a smaller problem? Also, that first number `2147483648` is 2^31. Are you sure you're initializing everything?

Comment: When I run smaller problems the script runs fine. But it might still be on the GPU...

Also, I edited to include something else showing the gpu is involved. See above. Thx

Comment: It works fine on smaller problems because you're only requesting block sizes that are valid. What is `CNN_FC_LANGUAGE`? What library is this? What does their documentation say? What LANGUAGE is the host code in?

Comment: CNN_FC_LANGUAGE is a class written in python which uses tensorflow's c++-code. And their documentation says that if you use with tf.device("cpu:0"): then no GPU allocation at all should happen. (I hope I understood your questions and replied to them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GPU version of TensorFlow will always attempt to initialize the GPU runtime (including devices and allocators) if one is available and, [as X3liF observes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40870101/3574081), the error you are seeing comes from allocating host (i.e. CPU) memory that can be accessed more efficiently in case you try to use the GPU.

To avoid using any GPU resources at all, you can set the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable when starting Python. Let's say your code is in a file called `my_script.py`:

```
# An empty CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES will hide all GPUs from TensorFlow.
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" python my_script.py
```

Comment: Others may find `import os; os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = ''` more helpful, eg for making tests run on the CPU without attempting GPU access at all. Importantly, `os.environ` changes are NOT persisted outside of the Python process, so this won't affect anything you have actively running or start after the test/script.

Answer (score 3):

Pinned memory is allocated with a call to *cudaMallocHost*.
this method doesn't allocate global GPU memory, the memory is allocated on the host side, but with some properties to allow faster copy through PCI-Express.

Moreover, cudaMallocHost needs contiguous memory, maybe your memory is fragmented into small sparse allocations and cudaMalloc fails.

Comment: My question is more a tensorflow question I guess. Tensorflow should NOT allocate any op on the GPU, thus the whole issue of cudaMalloc should not be relevant. Or am I totally wrong here?

Comment: i've edited my answer, cudaMallocHost allocates memory on the host side, not on the device side.